# copy a file to user document folder while installing a package created with pkgbuild command

Tags: swift, macos, installation, pkgbuild

is it possible to copy additional files to user document folder while installing a package created using **pkgbuild** terminal command on a Mac. can we do it with a *post-install* script. where we keep the source files to copy and how to specify the path in the post install script. Is there any options with productbuild to do the same.